# Turf.buffer and a draggable marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, geojson, turfjs

So far I have created a marker, transfered it to geoJSON, and created a buffer around it with Turf.buffer. How can I get this buffer to "stick" to the marker as I drag it around the map?

```
   <script>
        L.mapbox.accessToken = 'fg.eyJ1IjoisdflksdaklsjZWwiLCJhIjoiRHNwX0ZWNCJ9.Ov2O5sslkdqV93_R0lq3Q';
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'example.kf6j9ec4')
            .setView([38.633, -90.319],12);

        var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(38.633, -90.319), {
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                'marker-color': '1B05E3', 
                "marker-symbol": "pitch"
            }),
            draggable: true
        });

        marker.bindPopup('This marker is draggable! Move it around to see what locales are in your "area of walkability".');

        //Make the marker a feature
        var pointMarker = marker.toGeoJSON();

        //buffer the marker geoJSON feature
        var buffered = turf.buffer(pointMarker, 2, 'miles');

        var resultFeatures = buffered.features.concat(pointMarker);
        var result = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": resultFeatures
        };

        L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(buffered).addTo(map);
        marker.addTo(map);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of the above code and a lot of googling I came up with a solution which works. What worked: adding a draggable marker and then using the "marker.on" method to initiate a function to clear any old buffers and then a function to redraw the buffer around the current location.

```
        //add marker that is draggable
        var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(38.633, -90.319), {
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                'marker-color': '1B05E3', 
                "marker-symbol": "pitch"
            }),
            draggable: true
        });

        //add marker popup
        marker.bindPopup('This marker is draggable! Move it around to see what locales are in your "area of walkability".');
        marker.addTo(map);

        //remove old buffers (used when marker is dragged)
        function removeBuff(){
            map.removeLayer(buff);
            };

        //create buffer (used when the marker is dragged)
        function updateBuffer(){
            //Make the marker a feature
            var pointMarker = marker.toGeoJSON();
            //buffer the marker geoJSON feature
            var buffered = turf.buffer(pointMarker, 1, 'miles');
            //add buffer to the map. Note: no "var" before "buff" makes it a global variable and usable within the removeBuff() function. 
            buff = L.mapbox.featureLayer(buffered);
            buff.addTo(map);
        };

        marker.on('drag', function(){removeBuff(), updateBuffer()});
        updateBuffer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Upfront, i've got to say, i'm not familiar with Turf.js at all so shoot me if i'm wrong. One thing i don't understand about what you're doing is why are you adding `buffered` to the `featureLayer` and not the `result` object? I suppose you meant to do that so i changed that in my example below.

You'll need to hook onto the marker's `dragend` event. There you'll need to get the new results based on the marker's current geojson object. So it's best you write a function to get the results, so you can use that when placing the marker the first time and on each marker drag. In code:

```
// Add empty featureLayer
var layer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(38.633, -90.319), {
    draggable: true
});

// Attach handler on dragend event
marker.on('dragend', function (event) {
    // Get new results based on marker's current geojson
    var results = getResults(event.target.toGeoJSON());
    // Add the results to the featurelayer
    layer.setGeoJSON(results);
});

marker.addTo(map);

// Function for getting results
function getResults (geojson) {
    // You returned buffered, makes no sense to me
    // Changed it to return the new featurecollection
    // But you can alter it to what you need
    var buffered = turf.buffer(geojson, 2, 'miles'),
        resultFeatures = buffered.features.concat(geojson);
    return  {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": resultFeatures
    };
}

// Get results the first time
var results = getResults(marker.toGeoJSON());
// Add the results to the featurelayer
layer.setGeoJSON(results);
```

Now you'll have updated results on each marker drag. Did this code quick and dirty and was not able to test it because i don't know how to use turf. Otherwise i would've created an example on Plunker. Let me know if you run into any problems. Hope that helps, good luck!