# Drag marker and update Turf.js buffer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, turfjs

I'm trying to create a map where a marker is draggable and it buffer move along. Very similar (almost the same) than what this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867243/turf-buffer-and-a-draggable-marker) is dealing with, the thing in my case is that I'm not using Mapbox.js only plain leaflet. My current code is:

```
 //add marker that is draggable
 var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(39.75621, -104.99404), {
                      draggable: true});

 //add marker popup
 marker.bindPopup('This marker is draggable! Move it around to see what locales are in your "area of walkability".');
 marker.addTo(map);

 //remove old buffers (used when marker is dragged)
 function removeBuff() {
     map.removeLayer(buff);
 };

 //create buffer (used when the marker is dragged)
 function updateBuffer() {
     //Make the marker a feature
     var pointMarker = marker.toGeoJSON();
     //buffer the marker geoJSON feature
     var buffered = turf.buffer(pointMarker, 1, 'miles');
     //add buffer to the map. Note: no "var" before "buff" makes it a global variable and usable within the removeBuff() function. 
     buff = turf.featurecollection([buffered]);
     L.geoJson(buff).addTo(map);
 };

 marker.on('drag', function () {
     removeBuff(), updateBuffer()
 });
 updateBuffer();
```

This give me a buffer and allow me to drag the point and buffer along, however, the all previous buffers stay in the map.

I did a few changes in order to substitute the mapbox.js functions from that question so my guess is that this may be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that problem was in `buff = turf.featurecollection([buffered]);` one I changed to `buff = L.geoJson(buffered);` everything works.